# Expression of mass flow rate for steady flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mass, conservation-laws, flow

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate) the mass flow rate is given by:

$${\dot {m}}=\iint _{CS}\rho \mathbf {v} \cdot {\rm {d}}\mathbf {A}$$

And using the Reynolds Transport Theorem (if there is no sources):

$$\dfrac{dm_{sys}}{dt} =\iint_{CV}\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}\mathrm dV\llap{--} + \iint _{CS}\rho \mathbf {v} \cdot {\rm {d}}\mathbf {A} = 0$$

If the flow is **steady** then:

$$\dot m = 0$$

But as far as I know the mass flow rate for steady flow is also given by $$\dot m = \rho\cdot V \cdot A$$
And it will never be zero (if $\rho$, $V$, and $A$ are not zero)

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working through the math:

$$
\dot{m} = \frac{dm}{dt} = \iiint_{CV} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV + \iint_{CS} \rho \vec{V}\cdot dA
$$

If the flow is steady, all time derivatives are zero and you are left with:

$$
0 = \iint_{CS} \rho \vec{V} \cdot dA
$$

If we consider a 1D flow just as an example, this will give you:

$$
0 = -u_{\text{left}} \rho_{\text{left}} A_{\text{left}} + u_{\text{right}} \rho_{\text{right}} A_{\text{right}}
$$

or

$$
u_{\text{left}} \rho_{\text{left}} A_{\text{left}} = u_{\text{right}} \rho_{\text{right}} A_{\text{right}}
$$

which is an expression that is probably familiar. So, that all shows that $\dot{m} = 0$.

Now to your other equation, $\dot{m}_{\text{system}} = \rho V A$. That doesn't hold for steady flow. So the part you are missing is that your second statement isn't true, and there's no way to get this expression from the equation we started with if we assume the flow is steady. This expression will sometimes show up when specifying boundary conditions, as in $\dot{m}_{\text{in}} = \rho V A$ -- but if it is steady, that means that $\dot{m}_{\text{out}} = \rho V A$ also and the total $\dot{m}$ of the system is zero.

In other words, if you see something that says $\dot{m} = \rho V A$ and it also says the flow is steady, it means they are specifying the $\dot{m}$ across one of the control surfaces. Not all of the control surfaces.

Comment: Sorry you are explaining assuming that I am an expert. I am totally a beginner please use simple explanation. I cannot understand it sorry.

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician Which part don't you understand? Are you familiar with derivatives and integrals, dot products? I can try to clarify specific parts you are unsure about depending on what the confusion is.

Comment: Now to your other equation, $m_{system}=ρVA$. That doesn't hold for steady flow.

Comment: I cannot understand what is the difference

Comment: Right -- so your question said "But as far as I know... for steady flow... $\dot{m} = \rho V A$." I'm telling you that isn't true. It does not hold for steady flow for the system mass flow. The only true expression for the system is $\dot{m} = 0$.

Comment: Why it doesn't hold???? I can find the expression $\dot m = \rho V A$ everywhere.

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician If you read my answer, I explained where you will see it. It is *not* true for the **mass of a system**. If you see somebody say $\dot{m} = \rho V A$, they are talking about the mass flow *across a control surface*. Like $\dot{m}_{in} = \rho V A$. Implicit in that statement for a steady flow is that $\dot{m}_{out} = \rho V A$ also, because $\dot{m}_{system} = \dot{m}_{out} - \dot{m}_{in} = 0$

Comment: Thank you very much. I never thought about this.

Comment: The last question please: $\dfrac{dm_{sys}}{dt} = 0$ does it hold only in the CV or just everywhere?

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician Well, we don't know/can't assume anything about what happens outside of our system. If we want to know what is happening outside of our CV, then we expand our CV to include those regions. Does that make sense? The CV surrounds our system of interest. But I suppose it is possible to have an unsteady system that feeds a steady one -- like if you had a pipe that had two inlet valves. The two valves could be unsteady, but there would be a CV somewhere downstream in the pipe that was steady.

Comment: But why both have the same name: mass flow rate??

Comment: @Navaro They aren't really the same name. $\dot{m} = \rho V A$ is the mass flow rate through a surface or through a system. $\dot{m} = dm/dt$ is the change of mass in a system, which is not called mass flow rate. It is due to the change of density within the system (the volume integral) and mass flow rate into/out of the system (the surface integral). They have the same symbol, but not the same name.